# Binary search on an indexed collection (a sorted, indexed sequence)

Tags: scala, indexing, binary-search

I have an **indexed** collection (it must be indexed) of some type `A`:

```
var coll: IndexedSeq[A]
```

I wish to keep `coll` sorted according to some `Ordering[A]` but I am frequently adding/removing items to/from it. The obvious mechanism to do this is something like:

```
def binarySearch[A : Ordering](a: IndexedSeq[A], elem: A): Int
def add(a: A) {
  val idx = binarySearch(coll, a)
  coll = (coll take idx) :+ a +: (coll drop idx)
}
```

But there is neither a `binarySearch` in the standard library (odd, seeing as there is `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort`) and there is no datatype I can find that is both indexed and sorted (I guess that this is an inefficient structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `slice` on `TreeSet` is reasonably efficient (and you can use it with a one-element range), but you're right--it's strange that there is no indexed sorted data structure.  And it's efficient enough; most any sorted tree can be used that way if the number of children are tracked.  I think it's just an oversight that it's missing.

You can always use a set for repeated elements if you wrap them with a tag that only allows reference equality, and you can make sure they're ordered:

```
class Tag[A](val value: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) extends Ordered[Tag[A]] {
  def compare(ta: Tag[A]) = {
    val c = ord.compare(value,ta.value)
    if (c != 0) c
    else if (this eq ta) 0
    else System.identityHashCode(this) compare System.identityHashCode(ta)
  }
  override def toString = value.toString+"'"
  override def hashCode = value.hashCode
  override def equals(a: Any) = a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] eq this
}

scala> collection.immutable.TreeSet[Tag[Int]]() ++ List(1,2,3,2,1).map(i => new Tag(i))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Tag[Int]] = TreeSet(1', 1', 2', 2', 3')

scala> res1.slice(2,3).head
res2: Tag[Int] = 2'
```

This does add a lot of overhead for a comparatively simple task, however.

Comment: A Tree has *O(log n)* element access. I suppose `IndexedSeq` means *O(1)* access. Also there can't be a *O(1)* (for insert) sorted collection based on `Ordered`, since sorting by pairwise comparison is at least *O(n log n)*.

Comment: @ziggystar - `IndexedSeq` is not guaranteed to be _O(1)_ access.  Look at `List`!

Comment: @RexKerr `List` is not an `IndexedSeq` and `IndexedSeq` are indeed supposed to have "constant-time or near constant-time element access and length computation" (scaladoc 2.9.1).

Comment: Interesting - I guess indexed-based access here is not going to be O(1) - this could be problematic because this is a backing data structure for a `TableModel`

Comment: @oxbow You can have *O(1)* read access, but not *O(1)* write access. This is demonstrated by your example in the OP.

Comment: Yes - I think that O(1) read access (by index) is going to be important; I'm probably content with O(log n) read access

Answer (score 2):

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.Searching$$SearchImpl

> Search within an interval in the sorted sequence for a specific element. If the sequence is an IndexedSeq, a binary search is used. Otherwise, a linear search is used.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

```
def getPerson(userList: ArrayList[Person], person: Person): Integer = {
var low = 0;
var high = userList.size - 1

while (low <= high) {
  var mid = low + (high - low) / 2
  var midValue = userList.get(mid)
  if (person.firstName < midValue.firstName) {
    high = mid - 1;
  } else if (person.firstName > midValue.firstName) {
    low = mid + 1;
  } else {
    return mid
  }
}
return -1
```

}

Comment: can you add explanation and explanation to this for the person who asked, it will help you gain upvotes too